# Restrict Search Results to Post Author

Tags: search, author

Is there a way to restrict search results to only those posted by the logged in user?  I have a front-end form the user fills out.

Every user has a front-end dashboard and is able edit their own post.  Since they may have many posts I would like them to be able to search for their own posts, but not display posts from other authors (this would only complicate things) Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
function my_search_filter($query){
  if($query->is_search)
    $query->set('author', get_current_user_id());

  return $query;
};

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'my_search_filter');
```

Comment: thank you for the info, not sure how to implement it though.  I placed it in the functions.php - but I'm still able to search for other author's posts.

Comment: Doesnt it work as intended?